# How to open this form with accordion in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

We are building a search form and trying to implement it inside accordion so the user can click it to open the form. Here is the code:

**TS.**

```
buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: new FormControl(''),
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      agefrom: new FormControl(''),
      ageto: new FormControl(''),
      country: new FormControl(''),

    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>
    <form  [formGroup]="form">
        <ion-list style="margin-top: 15% !important" class="scroll">
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
           <ion-select interface="action-sheet" class="select" placeholder="Country">
              <ion-option ngDefaultControl [value]='country.name' *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.name}}
              </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
           </ion-item>    
                <button ion-button block class="search">Sign Up</button>                
        </ion-list>
    </form>
   </ion-list>
```

How to create an accordion which will include this form inside of it?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If not, you could look at their documentation concerning accordions: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example - I do this for my Angular app and just create an accordion (just like in the example on their website) and put the form inside the card-body

Comment: or you could create your own: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH33gmOHJMU

Comment: I am using https://demo.mobiscroll.com/collapsible/accordion. It is really very googe for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you need to create your own accordion. 
I have created a small example to demonstrate how an accordion can be achieved.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-accordion

You can further apply css animations to make it look and feel better.

Please, upvote if this helps!

Comment: It looks a bit different. There are almost 8 inputs and selects together in Ionic component. Also, it should be just one accordion inside which should be all forms together.

Comment: The optics are irrelevant in this case. What you want to achieve is have an element with (click) handler that calls a function in your component. (click)="toggleFunc()" in this function the magic happens and have a this.isExpanded: boolean in your component. Then you can judge what is displayed based on that variable value in your template.

Comment: Hmm. I am confused(( So how will look like complete sample according to my code inside the questions?

Comment: I tried to find tutorials for such a case. But there was not a suitable example.

Comment: I have created a demo and updated my answer. Check it out and upvote if helps! Cheers

Comment: Thanks it works. So I can just include the whole above code instead of that p tag right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can put whatever you want inside the <div class="panel">. It will get a class active once opened is true. And that is happening on (click) - firing the toggleFunc

Comment: When I include the form inside this code it throws this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159115/unexpected-closing-tag-ion-list-in-ionic-3?noredirect=1#comment97066369_55159115