# Unexpected closing tag ion-list in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

I checked many times and didn't see any problem. It throws an error for a closing tag of ion-list inside HTML.

**Component**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="toggleFunc();" class="accordion">Section Title</button>
  <div class="panel" [ngClass]="opened ? 'active' : ''">
    <form  [formGroup]="form">
      <ion-list style="margin-top: 15% !important" class="scroll">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input class="input-field" formControlName="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
     ...
     ...
              <button ion-button block class="login-button" (click)="search(form.value)">Search</button>                
      </ion-list>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Page**

```
<ion-content>
<app-search></app-search>
  <div class="group">
    <ion-grid>
...
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Problem is coming from search component's HTML. What is wrong? And how can be it fixed?

Comment: If possible can you post the console error which you get ?

Comment: @Lokkesh here is the message ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "ion-list". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see

Comment: You probably have two closing tags for your <ion-list>. Please search for </ion-list> in your component and remove the superflous tag. Also it might help to post all of your components HTML code otherwise it'll be impossible to help you any further.

Comment: Above ones are the only ion-list tags

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the problem is. De facto, you provide two templates above.
I created a small demo which I think represents exactly what you are looking for. Take a look at it here ;)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-accordion

Do not forget to upvote if it helps. 
Cheers!